# BufferedOutputStream instance returning null in Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, amazon-ec2, stream

I have following code written in a Spring Boot application which runs on an Amazon EC2 instance (Ubuntu):

```
String userFile = "myfile.txt";
BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(userFile));
```

It is working totally fine on my local host but when I deploy my .jar to prod server (mentioned above), `stream` is `null` while `userFile` is a valid file path. Any valid reasons? Something to do with Server Space or Permissions? Something to do with Server Configuration file?(**application.yml** in my case)

Comment: `stream` cannot **return** `null`, as it is not a function. Do you mean `stream` **is** null, so has the value `null`? This would be impossible after a constructor call, without a try-catch block ignoring exceptions.

Comment: Yeah, `stream` cannot be `null`. Even if it is an issue with permission or  drive space, you'll get an exception. Maybe you're swallowing exception somewhere else. Can you show us a whole method?

Comment: You have caught and ignored an exception and returned null instead. What was the exception? The answer to that is the answer to your question.

Comment: @FlorianAlbrecht Yes, stream is null. Edited that. After this in my finally block, I did stream.close(); So it is throwing null pointer exception there.

Comment: @BohdanLevchenko It working fine on local host but giving error on prod. Actually null pointer is thrown on stream.close(); Please see my above comment.

Comment: @EJP You are right. Please see my above comments.

Comment: So what is the answer to my question?

Comment: @EJP Sorry, I wanted to mention that this code is executed in a Try block. In Finally block, I am trying to close this stream as stream.close(); There it is throwing nullPointerException.

Comment: Sigh. There was a *prior* exception, that prevented the assignment to `stream`, so it stayed null. **What was that exception?** Therein lies the entire answer to your question. And you should always post *all* the relevant code when you ask a question here. Do it now.

Comment: Any way - the question is incomplete. @Perry, your code **must** include the line where the NullPointerException occurs. And to solve your problem: Adjust your finally block to **only** close stream when it is not null. Then you will see the original exception (if you do not ignore it anywhere).

Answer (score -1):

Does myfile.txt exist? I would expect some sort of issue if not. Try adding

```
userFile.createNewFile();
```

It will throw some exception if it is unable to complete.

Comment: Complete waste of time. `new FileOutputStream()` already creates the file. Now it will have to delete this one first. You haven't identified the real problem.

Comment: The API doesn't guarantee that a file will be created. BTW, I answered your question with a question that you never answered.

Comment: `new FileOutputStream()` *does* guarantee exactly that, unless there is an exception, or unless you specify 'append' mode and the file already exists. Trying to second-guess it remains pointless. I don't know what your final sentence refers to.

Comment: @Steve11235 Yes, myfile.txt surely exist.

Comment: Just to clarify. From the Java 8 API, "A file output stream is an output stream for writing data to a File or to a FileDescriptor. Whether or not a file is available or may be created depends upon the underlying platform. Some platforms, in particular, allow a file to be opened for writing by only one FileOutputStream (or other file-writing object) at a time. In such situations the constructors in this class will fail if the file involved is already open."

Comment: The Javadoc *specifically states* that a `FileNotFoundException` is thrown if the file cannot be created, or for several other reasons. All that stuff you quoted describes the reasons why an exception may be thrown. Or are you seriously claiming that a file may not be created and no exception thrown? And that any amount of data can be written to the resulting stream and just disappear into the ether?  And that `File.createFile()` can magically create a file where `new FileOutputStream()` can't? It's ridiculous.

Comment: No. I'm quoting the Javadoc, which states that there is no guarantee that the file will be created by the method.

Comment: It [*also states*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream(java.io.File)) 'Throws: `FileNotFoundException` if the file exists but is a directory rather than a regular file, does not exist but cannot be created, or cannot be opened *for any other reason*' [emphasis added]. Read it. You are *selectively* quoting the Javadoc, and you are also jumping to unwarrantable and indeed ridiculous conclusions.